# How do I programmatically delete cookies in Safari 8.0 on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, cookies, safari, terminal, fswatch

In Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25.1) on OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite), I visit some sites like google.com, apple.com, facebook.com and can then see the cookies when I click "Safari" -> "Preferences..." -> "Privacy" -> "Details..."

I then quit Safari completely (actually quit, not just close the window), and delete the following things using the following.

`rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/
rm -r ~/Library/Cookies
rm -r ~/Library/Safari`

When I restart Safari, the cookies are still there and I'm still logged in to a website that stored a cookie after login.

Which files do I need to delete or what do I have to do to get Safari to actually delete the cookies?

I need to be able to move/rename the files/directories and then move them back at a later time.  Cocoa Cookies can delete the cookies (http://ditchnet.org/cocoacookies/) and when I use [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) there are no interesting files that change.

Comment: I am stuck on the same thing. From what I understood, the Cookies.binarycookies file stores the cookies. I deleted that file, and it agains comes back (dont know from where!)

Comment: I knew cookies were stored in `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies`.
I made a script that parses and filters safari cookies. However after 10.10 every change made to that files seems to be completely ignored, even deleting it.
It seems they are cached somewhere else but I have no idea where.
The only way I'm aware of is using the official [api](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/sharedHTTPCookieStorage)

Answer (score 3):

I think Apple Script is the road to take here, give a look at [the linked blog entry here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2013/03/deleting-safari-cookies-via-applescript/). Below I copied the google script example.

```
 1  set deCookie to {"nytimes.com", "go.com", "cnn.com"}
 2  
 3  tell application "System Events"
 4    tell process "Safari"
 5      keystroke "," using command down
 6      delay 1
 7      tell window 1
 8        click button "Privacy" of tool bar 1
 9        delay 3
10        repeat with d in deCookie
11          click button "Details…" of group 1 of group 1
12          try
13            keystroke d
14            delay 1
15            select row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1
16            click button "Remove" of sheet 1
17          end try
18          click button "Done" of sheet 1
19        end repeat
20      end tell
21      keystroke "w" using command down
22    end tell
23  end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late I know, but I made [RemoveCookie](https://github.com/robmathers/RemoveCookie), a command line utility that deletes Safari cookies. Pretty straightforward, it uses the [NSHTTPCookieStorage API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/), which anyone looking to manage Safari cookies may find useful.